# use session bean to insert data with JPA

Tags: java, servlets, jpa, ejb

In a servelt, I try to call the session bean method to insert data to database via JPA. The insert process is written in the session bean.

I tried another example, which I select data from DB. The "select" works good. But I have no idea that why insert does not work.

The error information is:

HTTP Status 500

description: The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception: javax.ejb.EJBException

note: The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 logs.

I think there is something wrong with "tx.commit()", when I comment it then there is no error. But I do not know what the exactly problem.

Here is the bean class

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class testSession {

  public testSession() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  public void insertData(){
    EntityManagerFactory emf;
    EntityManager em;

    //the Entity Class-Category
    Category cat=new Category();

    //set value
    cat.setId(5);
    cat.setName("test cat");

    //the "test" is the persist unit in persistence.xml 
    emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    em=emf.createEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction tx=em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    em.persist(cat);
    tx.commit();
    em.close();
    emf.close();

  }
}
```

In the servlet

```
@WebServlet("/testServlet")
public class testServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EJB
testSession ts;

public testServlet() {
   super();
}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.print("<html><body>");
    //call the method in the session bean to insert data
    ts.insertData();
    out.print("</body></html>");
}


}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the full stractrace in order to found the culprit and a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need Injection via @PersistenceContext
The EntityManager itself is created by the container using the information in the persistence.xml, so to use it at runtime, we simply need to request it be injected into one of our components. We do this via @PersistenceContext

The @PersistenceContext annotation can be used on any CDI bean, EJB, Servlet, Servlet Listener, Servlet Filter, or JSF ManagedBean. If you don't use an EJB you will need to use a UserTransaction begin and commit transactions manually. A transaction is required for any of the create, update or delete methods of the EntityManager to work.

Example:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class testSession {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyUNIT_PERSIS_IMPORTANT_View_THE_persistence.XML")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

  public testSession() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  public void insertData(){
    //the Entity Class-Category
    Category cat=new Category();

    //set value
    cat.setId(5);
    cat.setName("test cat");

    entityManager.persist(cat);

  }
}

Reference
http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-entitymanager/
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried your solution, it still does not work and display the same error info

Answer (score 0):

I have used maven to this demo

Demo

```
https://mega.co.nz/#!AxtRVQzB!MdwwOXA1e_VayWgwIdxGdREhd69QDb6la0yT0mLMaKA
```

to url to of servlet this

```
http://<HOST>/use-session-bean-to-insert-data-with-jpa/testServlet
```

SQL create

```
CREATE TABLE category (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`name` VARCHAR(200), 
PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Persistence.xml

```
...
<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
..
```

Java Servlet

```
import com.mycompany.ejb.testSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author I2B Boris
 */
@WebServlet(name = "testServlet", urlPatterns = {"/testServlet"})
public class testServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    testSession ts;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("<html><body>");
        //call the method in the session bean to insert data
        ts.insertData();
        out.print("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

Java EJB

```
package com.mycompany.ejb;

import com.mycompany.entities.Category;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
 *
 * @author I2B Boris
 */
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class testSession {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "test")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void insertData() {
        //the Entity Class-Category
        Category cat = new Category();

        //set value
        cat.setId(5);
        cat.setName("test cat");

        entityManager.persist(cat);

    }
}
```

Entity

```
package com.mycompany.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author I2B Boris
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Category.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.name = :name")})
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }
        Category other = (Category) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.mycompany.entities.Category[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: I use glassfish server. I tried as you showed, but it still get the same error message-the EJB exception from the session bean...